# Adding relationship to existing nodes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying out Neo4j for the first time. I'm using the 2.0-RC1 community edition.

I've created some nodes:

```
MERGE (u:User{username:'admin',password:'admin'})
MERGE (r1:Role{name:'ROLE_ADMIN'})
MERGE (r2:Role{name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'})
MERGE (r3:Role{name:'ROLE_REST_USER'})
```

and now I want to add relationships between the nodes. However, I **don't** want to clear out the existing database created with the script above, add the statements and run it again. I want to add relationships to the existing nodes. Google helped me find this:

```
START n=node(*), m=node(*)  
where has(n.username) and has(m.name) and n.username = 'admin' 
and m.name = 'ROLE_WEB_USER' 
create (n)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(m)
```

Which works fine (even though I don't understand all the syntax). However, I am aware that this finds any node with a username property and any node with a name property, instead of using labels to check that it has the right type of node.

How can I do the same using labels?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Neo4j 2.0 you can create schema indexes for your labels and the properties you use for lookup:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(username)
CREATE INDEX ON :Role(name)
```

To create relationships you might use:

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'admin'}), (r:Role {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'})
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)
```

The `MATCH` will use an index if possible. If there is no index, it will lookup up all nodes carrying the label and see if the property matches.

N.B. the syntax above will only work with Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1 and above.

Comment: r is not the best choice of a variable name for the second node, often r is designated as the variable name for the relationship.

Comment: How do you modify the query to create the relation only there isn't already one?

Answer (score 10):

**Update as of 4/2020:**
*The new Cypher syntax is as follows. as `'CREATE INDEX ON'` has been deprecated is..*

```
CREATE INDEX FOR (n:Label) ON (n.property)
```